# How to log Byte[] data in log4net using AdoNetAppender

Tags: c#, log4net, adonetappender

I want to log a gzip-compressed string, which will be in binary `Byte[]` format, in a `[varbinary](max)` SQL table column using log4net's `AdoNetAppender`.

My questions:

1) Is this possible? If so, what `dbType` I need to use as parameter in my config file below:

```
   <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Data" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2147483647" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="Data" />
    </layout>
  </parameter
```

2) Are there alternatives other than converting the value to a string and then logging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to log you binary Byte[] is to convert it to a base64 string. There is no way to pass a Byte[] type as value to log4net logging methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to Byte[] in your CommandText like this:

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO [LogServer]
    ([Date], [Logger], [message], [Exception], [BinaryMessage], [BinaryException]) 
    VALUES
    (@log_date, @logger, @message, @exception, cast(@message as varbinary(max)), cast(@exception as varbinary(max)) )"/>
```